# Delete or hide some values in drop down list which is populating by stored procedure using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I'm working on Classic ASP and JavaScript.

I have two dropdown lists: `Dropdownlist1` and `Dropdownlist2`. In first dropdown list it shows list of companies, in second dropdown list it shows departments.

When the user select the company A from 1st dropdown list so, it should show all of departments.

When the user selects the company B from 1st dropdown list, it should hide couple of departments in the 2nd dropdown list.

The dropdowns are populated from stored procedures.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using AJAX calls to populate this fields?

Comment: Please include the code you are using to show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways to go with:

You can either use AJAX to make a Request to get the options for your second dropdown by passing the selection of the first one (that's what most people would do). That would look something like this in your JS (not tested!)

(Edit: forgot to mention that the example below uses jQuery)

```
$('select#company').on('change', function () {
    $.ajax('/some-asp-file.asp', {
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'Company': $('select#company').val()
        },
        success: $.proxy(function(data){
            $('select#department').html(data);
        }, this)
    });
});
```

and something like this in `/some-asp-file.asp` (also not tested!)

```
<%
dim Company
dim Department, Departments

Company = trim(request.form("Company"))

if Company <> "" then

    Departments = ' // -> Result Array from your SP here where you pass in "Company"

    for each Department in Departments
%>
<option value="<%=Department%>"><%=Department%></option>
<%
    next

else
%>
<option value="-1">-</option>
<%
end if
%>
```

OR (the decision also depends on the amount of data you have) you could initially get ALL the data and store it in a JS object and replace it client-sided. This is probably more frustrating to code with all the double quote escaping in ASP etc, but I could write you a quick example if you insist.